# Unable to run Laragon on Windows 10

Tags: windows, laragon

[When starting the app with "Run as Administrator" or without it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1HF9.png)

I am trying to run Laragon on Windows 10, but I'm receiving this error 
"Exception EAccessViolation in module laragon.exe at 00154645"

Please and advise on how to have it up and running?!

Comment: Hi @Hesham! When you write a post, please explain what your problem is, not just an image.

Comment: Hi @Hesham. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No, I have not!

Comment: I downloaded xampp instead 

Comment: I am also getting same error while trying to open laragon is that due to xaamp installed on my system ? I have no idea why this error occured